# Error while adding a Fakes in VS 2012

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have VS 2012 Ultimate and I am trying to add a Fake.
I right click on a referenced assembly, choose "Add Fakes assembly".

But then I cannot build the project, I get this error:

> Error  1   The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts\Bin\ccrewrite.exe" "@fccrewrite.rsp"" exited with code -1. [\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Documents\tfs\DefaultCollection\xxx\Workflow.Test\obj\Debug\Fakes\mxs\f.csproj]   Workflow.Test

Comment: That's an error message from the Code Contracts rewriter and not necessarily related to fakes. Crank up the verbosity of the build process (Tools -> Options, Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run), then view the contents of the output window (View -> Output, Show output from: Build) and see if there's anything relevant in there. Make sure to clean your project first and build only the main project first before you build your test project containing the fakes. I'm not sure if CC and Fakes actually combine; normally you wouldn't need to use both in a single project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is coming from the Code Contracts rewriter, which has (or had) [a bug that prevents it from working over UNC paths](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/09aa0095-9fef-4576-a2a2-0e2c77c0cfa1/assembly-reference-on-network-drive-causes-rewrite-error?forum=codecontracts).

This is due to an escape-conversion bug that converts the leading `\\` to a `\`. You might notice that the path in square brackets starts with a single slash: `[\vmware-host\Shared...`

The workaround provided in the link above is to map a drive to the UNC path, and reference your project from that drive.

I should also point out that the link is from 2011. Things might have changed in newer versions of the Code Contracts extension, but I can confirm this issue was still present when I evaluated Code Contracts in the middle of 2014.

As has been pointed out in a comment, you can probably disable the rewriter for your Fakes assembly - I can't see why you'd need it there.